# I have to get all inputs coming under the division

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="label">
   Some text
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="x">
        <div class="container">
        <input type="text"></input>
        <select  class="ddl"><option>--</option></select>
        <div>
    <div>
<div>
```

I have a structure like above
See the codes below

```
$.each($('.label'), function (index, value) {

$(this) //code to be here

}
```

I have to get all inputs&ddl class, coming under the division next to class="label"

```
$(this).next("div input,.ddl") not working
```

Comment: First thing Your code has a typo.. is is actual code? `});` in last

Comment: May be this `$(this).next(".group").find("input, .ddl")`?

Comment: .find() is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('.label').each(function() {
    var inputsAndDdls = $(this).next('div').find('input, .ddl');
});
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JD97S/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).next('div.group').find('input,.ddl')
```

Use `.next()` and then `.find()`

Comment: If you use `:input` in the `find` function you don't need to specify the tag and class

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
$(".label").next().find("*")


$(".label").next().("div input,.ddl")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sudhAnsu63/8M4e6/)

Comment: this will get all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you must base your selector off of `.label` the following would work:

```
$(".label").next("div").find(":input").each(function(i,e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

If you can be more liberal with your selector use:

```
$(".group :input").each(function(i,e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

Notice that these selections use `:input` which finds all inputs on the page.  If you were to alter the markup by adding new inputs this selector would robust enough to discover the newly added inputs.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6BbGB/